# Showing that a certain sequence space with a certain metric is separable and connected

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X= \{(x_{n})_{n} :|x_{n}| \leq n,  \forall{n}\in\Bbb{N}  \}$ and define the metric $d$ on $X$ by $d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {a_n}{n^3}$, where $a_n=\text{max}\{ |x_{n}-y_{n}|,1 \}  $ if $x\neq{y}$.

> a) Is $(X,d)$ separable?
>
> b) Is $(X,d)$ connected?

For both parts, I planned to find an equivalent metric for $d$ but it is not easy for me. Since $a_n$ always dominates the usual metric, for any sequence $(x^k)_k$ in $X$ and for $x=(x_n)\in X$ we have $d(x^k,x)\ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {|x^k_{n}-x_{n}|}{n^3}$, so if $(x^k)_k \to x$ with respect to $d$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {|x^k_{n}-x_{n}|}{n^3} \to 0$ with respect to Euclidean metric as $k \to \infty$. I do not know how to proceed from here, but it seems to me that this will imply $(x^k)_k \to x$ with respect to the supremum metric.

For concepts like separability and connectedness, this metric space is tricky and unusual for me, so any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: The set $X$ is better written like this: $X=\{\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}:(\forall n)[n\in\Bbb N \wedge |x_n|<n]\}$

Comment: (Frankly, I don't think that there's a "correct" notation between yours or ajotatxe's notation, it comes down to preference, however yes it would be better if you specified that you are looking at real sequences)

Comment: In fact ajotatxe's notation is not correct. $(\forall n)[n\in\Bbb N \wedge |x_n|<n]$ should be replaced either by $(\forall n)[n\in\Bbb N \implies |x_n|\le n]$ or by $(\forall n\in\Bbb N)\;|x_n|\le n$ (or equivalently by yours).